# How to change Krypton label's color to red in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, krypton-toolkit, krypton

I am using krypton toolkit for my UI, but I am unable to change a krypton label's color to red, anyone knows how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the toolkit, but I'd assume they extend the regular Label class in .NET.  I know the .NET Label use this property, which is extended from the Control class:

```
public virtual Color BackColor { get; set; }
```

Right click the Krypton label object and click Go To Definition.  You want to look for a property with a Color object.  They should also have a summary of what the property does.